# Receiving error when minting NFT on Solana devnet Metaplex v1.2.0 candy-machine-ui

Tags: javascript, typescript, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

Running metaplex version to 1.2.0, and using 3 basic NFT's (stored on Arweave). When minting on devnet I receive a Timeout Error.

I have tried minting on Metaplex's candy-machine-ui and a separate ui that uses javascript. Both receive same error.
`Timeout Error caught`
`Error: Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction`
`at sendSignedTransaction`

Tried downgrading metaplex to v1.1.1; still, receive Timeout Error.

Tried the following RPC Hosts, still received Timeout Error:
-https://explorer-api.devnet.solana.com
-https://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/

The metaplex.devnet.rpcpool (came stock with candy-machine-ui) actually gives me CORS errors, but regardless still no mint.

Network has always been set to `devnet`

Tried the follwoing Candy Machine IDs: `64EFEgBcLZHhdb3Tr6BzCRKX23ktS2Ltk42RC3z9CPLP` & `492Mhv2Kx6Mp91D1xyrXgDA9ZKeeXSRg2rWuN6LA2Qg6`

Tried these `config.json`:

```
#candy-machine-ui

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

```
#custom ui

{
    "price": 0.1,
    "number": 3,
    "gatekeeper": null,
    "solTreasuryAccount": "MY_WALLET_ADDY",
    "splTokenAccount": null,
    "splToken": null,
    "goLiveDate": "25 Dec 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
    "endSettings": null,
    "whitelistMintSettings": null,
    "hiddenSettings": null,
    "storage": "arweave",
    "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
    "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
    "awsS3Bucket": null,
    "noRetainAuthority": false,
    "noMutable": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I take a look to both CandyMachineIds that you provided and was able to mint without any issue using the last version of [candy-machine-ui](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/tree/master/js/packages/candy-machine-ui) with this the Candy Machine `64EFEgBcLZHhdb3Tr6BzCRKX23ktS2Ltk42RC3z9CPLP`. Your second Candy Machine with ID `492Mhv2Kx6Mp91D1xyrXgDA9ZKeeXSRg2rWuN6LA2Qg6` has the goLiveDate setted at `Sunday, December 25, 2022 12:00:00 AM` so anyone will be able to mint that.

What did I do to be able to mint?

1. I git clone the latest version of candy-machine-ui into my laptop using `git clone https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex.git`
2. I move away the candy-machine-ui folder located at metaplex/js/packages/ to my Desktop.
3. I open a terminal on the candy-machine-ui folder that I moved to my Desktop.
4. I run `yarn` inside this candy-machine-ui folder.
5. I create a .env file inside candy-machine-ui folder with the following content

```
REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID=64EFEgBcLZHhdb3Tr6BzCRKX23ktS2Ltk42RC3z9CPLP

REACT_APP_SOLANA_NETWORK=devnet
REACT_APP_SOLANA_RPC_HOST=https://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

6. I ran `yarn start` and waited till the localhost appear.
7. I make sure to have 0.2 SOL in the wallet that I used to mint (0.1 mint price + fees)
8. I clicked mint button and minted successfully without any other issue.

Hope this can hep you solve, any issue add a comment to this answer to keep me updated

EDIT: I used Opera browser with phantom wallet to mint from the UI

Answer (score 0):

That is caused beacuse of the slow RPC you're using.

Follow one of these solutions:-

- Use a custom RPC from [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/)
- For a free and fast one, use `https://devnet.genesysgo.net/` (Devnet)

  `https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/` (Mainnet)